# android unit test Mockito ошибка при вызове verify()

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, mockito

При вызове Mockito.verify(view).showNoContent() ошибка 
Wanted but not invoked:
view.showNoContent();
-> at kz.retail.buyer.ui.favorite.FavoritePresenterTest.loadFavoriteStoresFailed(FavoritePresenterTest.java:187)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

```
@Mock
private FavoriteContract.View view;

@Mock
private BaseApp app;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new FavoritePresenter(view, app);
}

@Test
public void loadFavoriteStoresFailed(){

    when(app.getApiService()).thenReturn(service);
    when(service.getFavoriteStoreList(anyString())).thenReturn(Observable.error(new Exception()));

    presenter.loadFavoriteStore();
    Mockito.verify(view).showNoContent();
}
```

Comment: Сообщение говорит о том, что метод, который вы ожидаете, не был вызван. То есть тест не пройден

Comment: почему не вызвается?

Comment: Проверяйте код, который тестируете.